# Numerating verses with multiple stanzas

Tags: verse, poetry

I am scratching my head over the twist in the verse numeration when the poem is divided over multiple stanzas.

It seems that last verse of the first stanza is not counted.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verse}
\verselinenumbersleft
\poemlines{2}
\setlength{\vrightskip}{-3em}

\begin{document}

\poemtitle{Garden}

\begin{verse}
I used to love my garden \\
But now my love is dead \\
For I found a bachelor's button \\
In black-eyed Susan's bed. 

I used to love my garden \\
But now my love is dead \\
For I found a bachelor's button \\
In black-eyed Susan's bed.
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As mentioned in the accepted answer below, it is necessary to end each stanza with `\\!` for line numbering to work correctly. I've done a quick pass over the documentation and submitted a new version to CTAN; hopefully this clears things up a little.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The counting does not like the blank lines. In the `verse` environment, I would recommend to use the `\\!`-command in order to mark a new stanza. Even for the last line, which does not make a lot of sense... You may still use blank lines in between. Or you mark it with some `%%%%%%%%` to get a nicer syntax.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\verselinenumbersleft
\setlength{\vrightskip}{-3em}
\poemtitle{Garden}
\poemlines{2}
\begin{verse}
I used to love my garden \\
But now my love is dead \\
For I found a bachelor's button \\
In black-eyed Susan's bed.\\!
I used to love my garden \\
But now my love is dead \\
For I found a bachelor's button \\
In black-eyed Susan's bed.\\!
\end{verse}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the correct solution as described in the verse documentation.